# Is there a name for an element $z$ such that $\,zx = z = xz\,$ for all $x$?

Tags: semigroups, monoid, magma

Is there a general name for the following properties, (similar to the properties of existence of an additive identity, existence of multiplicative identity etc):

1. For any given set, the intersection with the empty set results in the empty set.
2. For any real number, multiplication with zero results in zero.

Comment: These could both be said to be examples of *absorbing elements*. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorbing_element

Comment: Existence of an absorbing element (or annihilating element/annihilator, or a zero element).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've heard **absorbing element** or **annihilating element** used for this ([Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorbing_element)).

So in your second example, we'd say that $0$ is an absorbing element for the operation $\times$ on $\mathbb{R}$.

In your first example, you'd have to specify a set in which you're working. I'd suggest formulating this as: for any set $S$, the element $\varnothing\in\mathcal{P}(S)$ is an absorbing element for the operation $\cap\,$.

Answer (score 4):

(2) is a consequence of the *ring axioms* (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_(mathematics)); in general, an element $x$ with the property that $x*y=x$ for every $y$ is called an *annihilator* for the operation $*$.

For (1), the set of subsets of $X$ (for $X$ fixed) forms a *Boolean algebra* (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra; this is the structure provided by intersection, union, and complement). Boolean algebras always have a least element $l$, with the property that $l\wedge x=l$ for every $x$ (where "$\wedge$" is intersection, in the case mentioned above).

Answer (score 0):

I would like to propose some definitions.  All deal with elements in a monoid $M$.

Proposal:

Let *the absorbing element* or *the absorbor* (under multiplication) refer to the unique element $x$ such that for all $y$ in $M$, $xy = x$.  This is also called *the zero element* or *zero*, denoted $0$.  This element does not necessarily exist in $M$.

Let *an absorbing element* or *an absorbor* (under multiplication) refer to any element $x$ such that there exists some $y \neq 1$ such that $xy=x$.

Let *the annihilating element* or *the annihilator* (under multiplication) refer to the unique element $x$ such that for all $y$ in $M$, $xy = 0$.  This element, if it exists, turns out to be zero.

Let *an annihilating element* or *an annihilator* (under multiplication) refer to any element $x$ such that there exists some $y \neq 0$ such that $xy=0$.

Defense:

I think there are places where we can absorb an element, but not send it to $0$.  If I introduce a new operation, I can have an absorbing element $a$ under that new operation where $ab \neq 0$.  This is the reason for the distinction between absorption and annihilation.

Also, if $M$ is a module over a ring $R$, and $m \in M$ and $r \in R$ are both nonzero, then I could have $rm = 0$.  In which case, I would say that $r$ is "an annihilator" even though it is not "the annihilator".  This is the reason for defining the new notions that use "an" and are not unique.  Similarly, we can say that $m$ is "an annihilatee" because it has an annihilator.  The set of all annihilatees in $M$ is called the *torsion* of $M$.

Thanks, would love to hear your opinions on this.